# calculating more the 19 digits of division

Tags: python, math, decimal, division

I want to make a python program that divides '1/7' in python **however** all I get is : `0.14285714285714285`. How can I compute more digits after the decimal?

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html ; The `Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)` example is near the top of the page.

Comment: You understand the rest of the digits are all the same, right?   ;)

Comment: i was going to use for something else to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `decimal` datatype instead of `float`. It's in the standard library.

There is an example of `1/7` with specified precision at the top of the [decimal docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

The decimal library will allow you to specify arbitrary precision. There is an example on the page [here](https://zetcode.com/python/decimal/). Otherwise you could write your own code to compute the digits.

```
def div(a,b,n):
    """return [w,d1,d2,...dn] where a/b=w.d1d2...dn

    Examples
    ========

    >>> div(1,7,10)
    [0, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8]
    >>> div(10,7,4)
    [1, 4, 2, 8, 5]
    """
    w, r = divmod(a, b)
    rv = [w]
    for i in range(n):
        w, r = divmod(r*10,b)
        rv.append(w)
    return rv
```